# How to copy only folders from a directory into another

Tags: node.js

I'm using ncp plugin to copy some folders from a directory into another, the source directory contains some files as well so I only want to copy the folders in it and their content, and this is what I tried:

```
async function copyAssets(exportFolderName) {
  const assets = glob.sync("**/", { cwd: distPath });
  return Promise.all(
    assets.map((asset) => {
      return ncpPromise(path.join(distPath, asset), path.join(exportPath, exportFolderName), {
        clobber: false,
      });
    })
  );
}
```

What I'm doing here is I get the folder names inside `distPath` using `glob.sync` and then I copy each folder and it's content into `exportPath + exportFolderName`.

My source folder looks like this:

[image]

But then I get some weird results:

[image]

As you can see the folders were not copied, instead it was their content that was copied.

How can I solve this ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried to play with 'glob' and 'ncp' modules, and this is my little understanding -

- `glob.sync('**/')` Gets directory names recursively
- `glob.sync('*/')` Gets directory names non recursively

Since you want to exclude files from source directory, but copy all directories as a whole, I think you should go with latter glob.sync

Now, playing with ncp -

- `ncp(source, destination)` Copies all files/directories in source to destination directory

So, I am guessing, the following would work for you -
`ncp(path.join(distPath, asset), path.join(exportPath, exportFolderName, asset))`

This should create the source asset directory, and then put files into it.

Comment: both patterns `*/` and `**/` worked for me, what I was missing is to concat `asset` for the destination folder, thanks